# Can I send ctrl+c(copy) command using SendKeys.Send()?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to send copy command using `SendKeys.Send("^{c}");` but by this way system works unstable: print 'c' character to input field, and ctrl is in keydown state, not keyup. 
(See, keydown is last)
[image: Spy++ for SendKeys.Send()]

I also tryed to emulate copy command using PostMessage, but it doesn't working.

```
        if (IsShiftDown)
        {
            var hWnd = GetWindowUnderCursor();
            SetActiveWindow(hWnd);

            try
            {
                SendKeys.Send("^{c}");
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { }

            uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
            uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
            uint VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
            uint VK_C = 0x43;

            //
            // Emulate user ctrl+c keydown
            // PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, 0x001D0001);
            // PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_C, 0x002E0001);
         }
```

Tell me please, how to solve the problem, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Could you give more details about what it is you're trying to achieve ? Maybe sending CTRL-C is not the only solution to the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference but based on the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx), you shouldn't put braces `{}` around `c` (this is for sending special keys). You can optionally put brackets `()`, so `"^c"` or `"^(c)"`

Comment: I'm working on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057423/send-copy-command-to-another-application)  question...

Comment: I have watched a lot of questions of this subject, but I haven't found an exact solution yet.

Comment: Why don´t you copy the data directly to clipboard using Clipboard function?

Comment: Because I send message to applications that aren't mine

Comment: So, if you are sending keyboard codes to third-party application, are you sure the application is ready to check that kind of combination (2 codes)? If it´s ready, send "^(c)" should function, certainly. But, I believe the best way to do it is providing a HOOK into that application process, not only sending keyboard codes - remember that if the app does not monitor GLOBAL ENTRY keyboard codes, you won´t get success without the HOOK directly into the app keyboard buffer/read function;